# UndefinedMethodException : Attempted to call an undefined method named "addCSS" of class "Tools"

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I just upgrade prestashop 1.6.* to 1.7.4.* . Prestashop backend is working fine but when I trying to visit prestashop shop I'm getting error which is following.

> UndefinedMethodException 
>   Attempted to call an undefined method named "addCSS" of class "Tools".
>   in jmshomecategories.php line 54

Also when I trying to change maintenance mode change also at that time I'm also getting screenshot error.

If someone knows the error then please help it will be the great help for me.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

jmshomecategories.php does not sound like a core file, I assume this is a module that might not be compatible with 1.7. as addCSS is not a method of Tools class.

In 1.7. you (better: the module) should use the method addCSS from the controller e.g. $this->context->controller->addCss()

BR

Comment: I had the module with the version 1.7.1 and it was working perfectly. It seems the change was made after....

Comment: Even in 1.7.1 there was no method addCSS (see https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.1.x/classes/Tools.php) - therefore it can only be that the module has changed and is now not compatible to 1.7 anymore.